# Rails CanCan authorization for my scenario involving Superadmin, client admin, client users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan

I am a newbie to ROR. I have the following Roles and their actions in my project

Superadmin [ thatz me ]
 -> Can Manage all

Clientadmin [admin user for each customer ]
 -> can Manage User, users of his organization
 -> can Manage Client Data, created by users of his organization

Clientuser [ user who can create, update their own data]
  -> can read Data, created by users of his organization [client]
  -> can create Data
  -> can update Data, created by him

### Models

Client
User
Data

### Association

Client has_many :users

User belongs_to :client
User has_many :datas

Data belongs_to :users

### Problem:

I have used devise for authentication. And trying to use CanCan for authorization. Need to authorize superadmin to manage all, and can I specify that "this user can see only datas created by users of his organization" if so how.

It will be more helpful if you help me with a sample code.

Thanks,
KGK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki page "Defining Abilities" has some good examples.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.clientadmin?
      can :manage, User, :client_id => user.client_id
      can :manage, Data, :client_id => user.client_id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have gone through that article. My problem is every user will be associated with a client_id and in case of superadmin what should i do for client_id. and how should I filter datas created by users of current_user's organization [client] using cancan. How should I disable the previous filter for superadmin.

Comment: You can apply conditions to an ability, like this: `can :manage, User, :client_id => user.client_id` (see example above)